# Optimize bruteforce solution of searching nearest point

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

I have non empty **Set** of points scattered on plane, they are given by their coordinates.
Problem is to quickly reply such queries:

> Give me the point from your set which is nearest to the point A(x, y)

**My current solution pseudocode**

```
query( given_point )
{
  nearest_point = any point from Set
  for each point in Set
    if dist(point, query_point) < dist(nearest_point, given_point)
      nearest_point = point
  return nearest_point
}
```

But this algorithm is very slow with complexity is `O(N)`.

The question is, is there any data structure or tricky algorithms with precalculations which will dramatically reduce time complexity? I need at least `O(log N)`

**Update**

By distance I mean Euclidean distance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get *O(log N)* time using a [kd-tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree). This is like a binary search tree, except that it splits points first on the x-dimension, then the y-dimension, then the x-dimension again, and so on.

If your points are homogeneously distributed, you can achieve *O(1)* look-up by binning the points into evenly-sized boxes and then searching the box in which the query point falls and its eight neighbouring boxes.

It would be difficult to make an efficient solution from Voronoi diagrams since this requires that you solve the problem of figuring out which Voronoi cell the query point falls in. Much of the time this involves building an R*-tree to query the bounding boxes of the Voronoi cells (in *O(log N)* time) and then performing point-in-polygon checks (*O(p)* in the number of points in the polygon's perimeter).

Comment: Yup kd-tree is the way to go for this problem.

Comment: thanks for reply, I found libraries of kd-trees. Now trying to implement kd-tree by myself

Comment: @oybek: If you're in a C++ environment, I've found [nanoflann](https://github.com/jlblancoc/nanoflann) to work well. Python has an implementation in SciPy. Not sure about other languages.

Comment: @Richard: currently I need algo in Java, found repo in github implementing kd-tree and other non standart structures

Answer (score 1):

You can divide your grid in subsections:

[image]

Depending on the number of points and grid size, you choose a useful division. Let's assume a screen of 1000x1000 pixels, filled with random points, evenly distributed over the surface.

You may divide the screen into 10x10 sections and make a map (roughX, roughY)->(List ((x, y), ...). For a certain point, you may lookup all points in the same cell and - since the point may be closer to points of the neighbor cell than to an extreme point in the same cell, the surrounding cells, maybe even 2 cells away. This would reduce the searching scope to 16 cells.

If you don't find a point in the same cell/layer, expand the search to next layer.

If you happen to find the next neighbor in one of the next layers, you have to expand the searching scope to an additional layer for each layer. If there are too many points, choose a finer grid. If there are to few points, choose a bigger grid. Note, that the two green circles, connected to the red with a line, have the same distance to the red one, but one is in layer 0 (same cell) but the other layer 2 (next of next cell).

Comment: yes, I thought about splitting area and found "voronoi diagram" data structure, the idea is that for each point you build a polygon which contains closest points for only given point

Comment: Well - it depends, whether points are added to your diagram or deleted, how often and how many queries you get. For generating a rough grid, you only need rounding and division and a 2dim Array of Lists of points. So for (x,y) 847,134 you would store the point at (84,13) and search from x:82 to 86 and y:11 to 15. After finding the nearest neighbor, you could store that value as well in a result map, to avoid a second search, even in the smaller subset of relative neighbors.

Comment: @oybek: It will be difficult to use a Voronoi diagram. I've updated my answer to comment on this.

Comment: @userunknown: If the points are "evenly distributed over the surface", then you know both the density of the points as well as well as the expected distance between them. From this you can choose an optimal grid size.

Answer (score 0):

Without preprocessing you definitely need to spend O(N), as you must look at every point before return the closest.

You can look here [Nearest neighbor search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) for how to approach this problem.